# Fetch image from JavaScript to flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch, easyocr

*Hi,
How to fetch matrix of images readed by cv.imread() in JavaScript to flask in backend and returned after using Easyocr as array of images.*

*Format of image is a matrix image readed by OpenCv (CV.imread(img) )*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLyhc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDoRN.png)

*CODE from python file(Backend): *

````
@views.route("/detect", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def detectText():
    print("getdatafromjavascript")
    im = request.files.get('snap')
    cv.imwrite(im)
    #readIm = cv.imread(im)
    #print(im.content_type)
    if im:
        # model = create_model()
        #img = cv.imdecode(np.frombuffer(im.read(), np.uint8), cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        img = cv.imread('test.png')
        # Detect objects
        # r = model.detect([img], verbose=0)[0]

        # masked_image = visualize.display_instances(img, r['rois'], r['masks'], r['class_ids'], ["BG", "culture"], r['scores'], show_bbox=True)
        # masked_image = cv.putText(img=np.float32(masked_image), text=f'{r["masks"].shape[2]} colonies', org=(50, 50),
        # fontFace=cv.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, fontScale=2, lineType=cv.LINE_AA, color=(256, 0, 0), thickness=2)

        img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        ret, buf = cv.imencode('.jpg', img)

        return send_file_data(buf.tobytes())
        reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=False)  # bedre om du har gpu og raaskere
        result = reader.readtext(im, detail=1, ycenter_ths=0.2, paragraph=False, width_ths=0.1)  # Matris
        i = 0
        imgs = []
        for text in result:
            i = 1 + i
            p1 = text[0][0]
            p2 = text[0][2]
            y1 = p1[1]
            y2 = p2[1]
            x1 = p1[0]
            x2 = p2[0]
            # cpx = text[0][2]
            detectedText = text[1]
            cropped = im[y1:y2, x1:x2]
            imgs.append(cropped)
        return imgs```

*CODE from JavaScript(Frontend): *

`function lastopp(data){
     // Create a form using FormData. This holds key value pairs.
    let from = document.getElementById('formIm')
        let formdata = new FormData();

        // Add a key value pair ("snap", file) to the FormData object. file is the original file passed sent to the upload function.
         formdata.append('snap', data);
         
    // The fetch() method returns a Promise and has the syntax of if true, do these sequential functions, else in the case of an error do Y.
    fetch("detect" , {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formdata,
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.blob();
    }).then(function(blob) {
        ocrIm.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Fetch problem: ' + err.message);
    });
}`







*I tried fetch and AJX*
````